# how to declare a multiple arraylist in python?

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, declaration

Sorry, i would like in automatic way:

- read multiple files
- create a multiple array
- affect data in array,

Thanks

```
#read files :
donnees_T_surf_1=open("simulation/1/GR_TG1.TXT",'r')
donnees_T_surf_2=open("simulation/2/GR_TG1.TXT",'r')
donnees_T_surf_500=open("simulation/500/GR_TG1.TXT",'r')

# declaration of array
T_surf_test_1, T_surf_test_2, T_surf_test_3, T_surf_test_4,
T_surf_test_5, T_surf_test_500=[], [], [], [], [], []
#affectation in array
for line in donnees_T_surf_1:
    donnees = line.strip().split()
    T_surf_1.append(float(donnees[0]))

for line in donnees_T_surf_2:
    donnees = line.strip().split()
    T_surf_2.append(float(donnees[0]))

for line in donnees_T_surf_500:
    donnees = line.strip().split()
    T_surf_500.append(float(donnees[0]))
```

I would like this result :

```
#read files :
for j in range(500) :
    donnees_T_surf.append(open(str(j)+"GR_TG1.TXT",'r')) 
# declaration of array
    for i in range(500) :
        T_surf_test_str(i) =[]
#affectation in array
for count in range(500) :
    for line in donnees_T_surf_str(i):
        donnees = line.strip().split()
        T_surf_str(i).append(float(donnees[0]))
```

when i run it, i obtain:

```
T_surf_test_str(i) =[]        
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Comment: When you say "double array", do you mean 2D list?

Comment: `T_surf_test_[str(i)]` is not doing what you think it would be doing.

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake